# umbraco administration section images not getting displayed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, umbraco

After I deployed my umbraco application on server the images in umbraco section are not being displayed. I even tried to make umbraco_client folder as virtual directory but it still didn't helped

[image]

Does any one have any idea. On my local machine everything is working file.
Umbraco version is 7.1.6

Comment: Try using a browser inspection tool to see where the image resource is supposed to be, and then double check the physical location of the resources on the deployment machine. Maybe you just forgot to include the image resource folder in the deployment job?

Comment: I tried using browser inspection tool but looks like its burried under some css or code call. unable to figure it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the following may help you.

1. May be this is permission related issue. Check if you have enough
   right to access that image folder.
2. Check in console. If path of images has been changed after deployment on server. You might be getting imagenotfound error in console.
3. May be font-awesome icons are not visible after deployment. (If this is your issue then let me know i have solution for it.)

Comment: I checked all permissions are ok.

Comment: can you please share font-awesome icons solution as well

Comment: Fixed with the help of http://edsykes.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/aspnet-build-actions-with-ttf-eot-and.html#!/2012/09/aspnet-build-actions-with-ttf-eot-and.html

Comment: Actually these were those issues which i have faced. Anyways happy that you got your point from above 3.